# Build error in carbide c++

Tags: carbide

I create a simple hello world project in carbide.c++ and i found these error ewhen i trying to build the project

I am using Sybmian^3 SDK and Carbide.C++.
Here is the console output

```
***Building project "hello" for configuration "Emulator Debug (WINSCW) [symbian]"

***Printing environment variables modified from default:
PATH=C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Tools\Command_Line_Tools;C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\t  ools;C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\gcc\bin;C:/Symbian/Tools/Carbide.c++    v2.7/jre/bin/client;C:/Symbian/Tools/Carbide.c++ v2.7/jre/bin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Symbian\tools;C:\Program Files\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin;\epoc32\tools\sbs\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Symbian\tools
=::=::\
MWCSYM2INCLUDES=C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++  v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C\MSL_Common\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C\MSL_Win32\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C\MSL_X86;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C++\MSL_Common\Include;+C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_Extras\MSL_Common\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_Extras\MSL_Win32\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\Win32-x86 Support\Headers\Win32 SDK;
MWSYM2LIBRARIES=C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\Win32-x86 Support\Libraries\Win32 SDK;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\Runtime\Runtime_x86\Runtime_Win32\Libs
 MWSYM2LIBRARYFILES=MSL_All_MSE_Symbian_D.lib;gdi32.lib;user32.lib;kernel32.lib;
MWCINCLUDES=C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C\MSL_Common\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C\MSL_Win32\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C\MSL_X86;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_C++\MSL_Common\Include;+C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_Extras\MSL_Common\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\MSL\MSL_Extras\MSL_Win32\Include;C:\Symbian\Tools\Carbide.c++ v2.7\x86Build\Symbian_Support\Win32-x86 Support\Headers\Win32 SDK;
EPOCROOT=\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\
NO_DEPENDENCIES=-nd
MAKE=make -j 4

Working Directory: C:/Symbian/Carbide/workspace/hello/group


  ***Invoking bldmake command
perl.exe -S bldmake.pl bldfiles winscw  
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
   defined(%hash) is deprecated at C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\/E32Plat.pm line 401.
(Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(%hash) is deprecated at C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\/E32Plat.pm line 451.
(Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
    defined(%hash) is deprecated at  C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\tools\/E32Plat.pm line 591.
(Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)

"\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\hello\group\BLD.INF" FATAL ERROR(S):
\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\hello\group\BLD.INF(26) :         \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\hello\group\ICONS_SCALABLE_DC.MK does not exist

=== BLDMAKE Command failed with error code 1 ===
***Stopping. Check the Problems view or Console output for errors.

***Errors were detected in build. See the Problems or Console view for details.

Total Time: 0 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

**[This link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?220979-Carbide.C-2.7-cannot-build-HelloWorld-App-2-errors)**  looks to be the same problem, suggesting that the message in your output:

```
"\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\hello\group\BLD.INF" FATAL ERROR(S): \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\hello\group\BLD.INF(26) :         \Symbian\Carbide\workspace\hello\group\ICONS_SCALABLE_DC.MK does not exist
```

is because the file you are looking for has been misnamed. Look for Icons_aif_scalable_dc.mk an rename it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right, as DaveRlZ mentioned.

clear description and solution is shown here

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/217613-ICONS_SCALABLE_DC-MK

worked for me